# jQuery plugin to scroll page, change background and fade back on anchor click?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

My nav looks like this:

```
<a href="index.html" class="nav">Home</a>
<a href="about.html" class="nav">About</a>
<a href="#" class="nav">Services</a>
<a href="contact.html" class="nav">Contact</a>
```

On index.html I briefly mention the two services offered and include a "read more" link for each one. It looks like this:

```
<div style="width:468px; height:180px; float:left; font-family:Lucida Grande,Lucida Sans Unicode,Calibri,Arial,sans-serif;font-size:13px;line-height:17px;color:#666666;">
<span class="article"><b style="font-size:14px; color:#000000">Service #1</span>
<div style="padding-right:24px; padding-top:6px;font-size:12px; line-height:18px; color:#333333">Description</div> <!-- end "div" -->
<a href="vpn.html" class="readmore">Read More</a>
<div style="clear:both; font-size:1px; line-height:1px;"></div> <!-- end "div" -->
</div> <!-- end "div" -->
<div style=" width:228px; height:180px; margin-left:12px; float:left; font-family:Lucida Grande,Lucida Sans Unicode,Calibri,Arial,sans-serif;font-size:13px;line-height:17px;color:#666666;">
<span class="article"><b style="font-size:14px; color:#000000">Service #2</b></span>
<div style="padding-top:6px;font-size:12px; line-height:18px; color:#333333">Description. <a href="#" class="readmore">Read More</a>
</div> <!-- end "div" -->
</div> <!-- end "div" -->
```

Instead of being redundant and creating a services.html page, only to say the same thing I do on index.html and include more "read more" links, I'd like to do something with jQuery (since I'm already using it + Cycle for testimonials.)

**When the services link is clicked, on whatever page, I would like it to go to index.html, scroll to the two `div`s describing the services, change the background color (to yellow) for emphasis, and then fade back to normal (white.)**

Is there a plugin for jQuery that will do this? Or how can I? I was looking at [bgFader](http://jdeerhake.com/bgFader.php) but since there's no demo I'm not sure this is what I'm looking for (and I don't know JS.)

**EDIT**

@Yi Jiang - It didn't work. I added this to my `<head>`:

```
<!-- include jQuery library --> 
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3.2/jquery.min.js"></script> 
<!-- include Color plugin --> 
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.color.js"></script> 
<script type="text/javascript"> 
if(window.location.hash === '#services') {
    var service = $('#services');
    var originalColor = $('#services').css('background-color');

    $('#services').css('background-color', '#FFEE9F').animate({
        'background-color': originalColor
    }, 1000);
}
</script>
```

And added `id="services"` to one `div` (for testing) and changed my anchor to `index.html#services`. It scrolls to the right place (thanks!) but it doesn't change the background or do anything besides scroll. Did I screw something up?

Answer (score 1):

Well, it's rather simple actually. First, to get the scrolling bit, you can use a hash to point to the relevant part of the document. Add an `id` to the `div` you want to scroll to, like say `services`, then use the URL `index.html#services` to get the link to automatically go to the homepage and scroll to the services part of the page.

Next, to get the highlighting, you'd want to use [`window.location.hash`](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/DOM/Window.location)  to see if you're pointing to the services section. Then we can use the [jQuery color plugin](http://github.com/jquery/jquery-color/blob/master/jquery.color.js) to get color animation. The code would look something like:

```
if(window.location.hash === '#services') {
    var service = $('#services');
    var originalColor = $('#services').css('background-color');

    $('#services').css('background-color', '#FFEE9F').animate({
        'background-color': originalColor
    }, 1000);
}
```

PS: You might want to clean up your HTML a bit. The `b` tag, for instance, is deprecated ans should not be used, and inline styles should also be moved to separate CSS files.

---

Edit: You need to wrap everything in a `$(document).ready` handler, as with all jQuery code, like this. Otherwise, change the duration so that it takes longer to return back to the original color, so that the change is more noticeable, and that the color plugin is correctly embedded:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    if(window.location.hash === '#services') {
        var service = $('#services');
        var originalColor = service.css('background-color');

        service.css('background-color', '#FFEE9F').animate({
            'background-color': originalColor
        }, 3000); // Change duration here
    }
});
```

Tabs shouldn't make any difference (not really sure which tabs you're referring to here)

Comment: Ah, many thanks! I'll let you know how it goes after dinner (and choose your answer if it's all gravy.)

Comment: It didn't work. I edited my original post for you (this comment wasn't long enough.)

Comment: @Matt See my edit. You're also using an old version of jQuery, FYI

Comment: Hmm still nothing. Do spaces/tabs matter in JS? Edit: I didn't notice that, I'm also using the min version... eh, I could have sworn I wasn't. Maybe that's the problem.

Comment: I switched to `http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.4.2.js` and it didn't solve the problem. If spaces/tabs matter in JS that's probably my problem... Programmer's Notepad is highlighting `$(document).ready(function(){` differently here compared to my `Cycle` plugins, and I'm guessing that's from spaces. But I'll wait for your reply first.

Comment: Edit: nope, I made them exactly the same... it's still highlighting the `$` differently though, weird.

Comment: That's exactly what I had, but I deleted & copy/pasted anyway - nada. And by tabs I was referring to `if(window.location.hash === '#services') {` I had put an extra tab in before the "if"... but you said it doesn't matter, and I've copy/pasted yours verbatim...